# Reduced costs of a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, solution-verification, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

If I have a linear programming problem in standard form, how can I prove that:

> If $x^*$ is the unique optimal solution of the LP problem, then the reduced costs of all nonbasic variables are strictly positive ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest proving the contrapositive.  Suppose some nonbasic variable has nonpositive reduced cost.  What happens if you pivot?